# SAS CONTRAST: "Weighting" for linear combination of parameter estimates in PROC GLM

Tags: testing, sas, contrast, categorical-data

*Background*: I have a categorical variable, *X*, with four levels that I fit as separate dummy variables. Thus, there are three total dummy variables representing x=1, x=2, x=3 (x=0 is baseline).

*Problem/issue*: I want to test the significance of a linear combination of my model's parameters, something like: 2*B1+2*B2+B3=0.

In Stata, the first issue can be done easily after a model is fit using the following:

`test 2*B1 + 2*B2 + B3 = 0`

Now, if I want to do this in SAS for `PROC GLM` using a `CONTRAST` statement, I know my "weights" (for lack of a better term) must sum to 0. For example, if, in an unrelated example, I wanted to test the following for four continuous variables: C1 + C2 = C3 + C4, my contrast statement would look like:

`CONTRAST 'Contrast1' C1 0.5 C2 0.5 C3 -0.5 C4 -0.5`

In this case, it's obvious how each variable should be weighted. However, when I want to combine the coefficients I gave in the model above (2*B1 + 2*B2 + B3 = 0) with these weights, it becomes unclear to me how to weight the function in the `CONTRAST` statement, specifically for a dummy variable-coded categorical variable, as described initially in the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PROC REG.

```
proc reg data=mydata;
model y = b1 b2 b3;
test 2*b1+2*b2+b3=0;
run;
quit;
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a difficult time keeping track of what statements each of SAS's multitude of regression procedures support. I didn't think of PROC REG because I had previously tried doing a simple *calculation* (as opposed to test) of a linear combination of parameters (i.e. use SAS as a "calculator" with the stored beta estimates), like Stata's `lincom` command, and PROC REG didn't support that. This is actually also something I need to be able to do so I will add it to my question.

Comment: Never mind - I think it's more appropriate as its own question. Will post new question now.

Comment: Additional, somewhat related, question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758486/sas-automatically-calculate-linear-combination-of-parameter-estimates-with-pr

Comment: Added an answer to your other question.  Short answer is PROC SCORE.

Comment: Thank you. I have commented on that question's posting.

Comment: And motivation for being able to do this in `PROC GLM` is to not have to first code dummy variables by hand. Will keep searching for other options...