# "Automatically" calculate linear combination of parameter estimates with PROC GLM

Tags: sas, categorical-data

*Background*: I have a categorical variable, *X*, with four levels that I fit as separate dummy variables. Thus, there are three total dummy variables representing x=1, x=2, x=3 (x=0 is baseline).

*Problem/issue*: I want to be able to calculate the value of a linear combination (i.e. using SAS as a calculator) of these dummy variables. For example, 2*B1 + 2*B2 + B3.

In Stata, this can be done using the `lincom` command, which uses the stored beta estimates to calculate linear combinations of the parameters.

In SAS in a procedure such as PROC GLM, I think I should use the `ESTIMATE` statement, but I'm not sure how I would specify the "weights" for each variable in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for PROC SCORE.  This takes output regression or factor estimates and scores a new data set.   See here for an example.  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/66859/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_score_examples02.htm

Comment: Thank you. To use this, it looks like I need to A) look for the linear combination of interest (if it exists) in the output data "manually" or B) set up IF/WHERE statements to get SAS to output the combination (again, if it already exists in the data). However, if I want some combination that doesn't already exist, would I need to add that person to the data set (outcome missing so it doesn't contribute to the regression), then predict the values and find it in the data set (by (A) or (B) above)? It's just...a lot of coding for something simple (but this is SAS, so...).

Comment: Just create a new data set with the values you want scored.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've also used PROC MODEL, but was hoping there was something with less coding.

Answer (score 2):

FYI, `PROC MODEL` does allow this in the model statement, which may be less work than `PROC SCORE`. I know `PROC MODEL` can be used readily in place of `PROC REG`, but I'm not sure how advanced of modeling `PROC MODEL` does, so it may not be an option for more complex models. I was hoping for something with less coding, but given the nature of SAS, I think this and `PROC SCORE` are the best I'm going to get.

Comment: PROC MODEL is the flagship procedure in the ETS package.  You can fit a lot of different types models with it.

Answer (score 0):

What if you add your linear combination as a variable in your input dataset?

```
data myDatasetWithLinCom;
set mydata;
LinComb=2*(x=1)+ 2*(x=2)+(x=3); /*equvilent to 2*B1 + 2*B2 + B3*/
run;
```

then you can specify LinComb as one of the explanatory variables and you can lookup the coefficient directly from the output.

Comment: I'm not sure that gives the correct answer (it is not the same as when I calculate by hand). I did what you showed above, then fit PROC REG with MODEL y=LinComb. Was this what you were implying?

Comment: Yes, but include other explanatory variables along with LinComb(but, not the variable which makes up LinComb).

Comment: It might be worth looking at `offset` option in `Proc Logistic` ( if you are dealing with binary classification): http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_logistic_sect010.htm#statug.logistic.logisticoffset

Comment: The outcome is continuous, predictors may be combination of categorical and continuous - this was a simplification. I'm looking for something that works very generally.

Comment: I did try it with the LinComb and then any other predictor that wasn't included in that linear combination, but it still didn't give the same result.